# Amazon s3 fast fileset download?

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an iphone app that sometimes has to download a set of files from a bucket on a Amazon AWS S3 account.

A typical such download will involve maybe 100 files. Most of these files are very small though and all combined, we are still under 3MB.

At the moment, I use the listObjectsInBucket function and then loop on all files and use the API/SDK function getObject to get them one by one.

The problem is that it takes a very long time to do it that way so I would like to have some advice regarding a faster strategy that would work in my scenario (many small files that have to stay available individually so that they can be modified by a CMS).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some reason the CMS deployment can't bundle the files?  Validating/Downloading one bundle of 3MB will be far more efficient than verifying 100 files and downloading each individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the files to remain resident in the application's local storage, it might make sense to store all the files locally along with metadata on the files (i.e. checksum, last modified timestamp, etc.).  You could then compare this metadata against metadata you store in S3 metadata fields, syncing up only those files where the metadata differs.

Comment: I already do that to some extent. saving the date of the last download and, the next time, downloading only those files which have been modified on the server since.

Comment: Well, an approach of that sort is probably all you can really do.